# Particular solution to $y'' - 3y' + 2y = 2e^x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

Im trying to find the particular solution to: $$y'' - 3y' + 2y = 2e^x$$

I already have the homogenous solution so this is not my problem.

Assuming that $y_p = Ae^x \to {y'}_p = Ae^x \to {y''}_p = Ae^x$ we have:

$$Ae^x - 3Ae^x + 2Ae^x = 2e^x$$
$$0 \cdot Ae^x = 2e^x$$
$$0 = 2$$

Which is very bad. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: $Ae^x$ is a solution to the homogenous equation, so it cannot be a particular solution. Try $Axe^x$...

Comment: When should I use $Ae^x$ and when should I use $Axe^x$ for the particular solution?

Comment: Usually, if you think a solution is logical, but you get 0, add an extra $x$. The idea is that when you differentiate this product, you get two terms each time:  Whenever you don't differentiate $x$ you get exactly the previous relation, thus 0; whenever you differentiate $x$ you get new expressions involving only your guess function... If you still get $0$, add an extra $x$ (meaning $x^2$), same argument tells you that whatever contains $x,x^2$ should vanish....

Comment: Thanks that was very helpful.

Comment: You might find these notes useful: http://www.math.ubc.ca/~israel/m215/undcoef/undcoef.html

Comment: Any differential equations textbook, when it discusses the method of undetermined coefficients, should explain what to do, even if it does not explain the theoretical reasons for doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is too long for a comment, so I posted it as an answer. First solve for the homogeneous equation $y'' - 3y' + 2y =0$ by setting the right hand side to be zero. The auxiliary equation is $m^2-3m+2=0$, which has roots $m=2,1$. Therefore the solution for this homogeneous equation is $e^x$ and $e^{2x}$. Now we want to find a particular solution $y'' - 3y' + 2y = 2e^x$. Normally we set the particular solution to be $Ae^{x}$. However, it duplicates with the solution of the homogeneous solution, therefore, we multiple it with $x$ until no duplication occurs. Therefore, the particular solution is given by $Axe^{x}$.

Let me do another example: to solve $y'' - 2y' + y = 2e^x$. First solve the homogenous equation $y'' - 2y' + y = 0$. The auxiliary equation is $m^2-2m+1=0$ which has double roots $m=1$. Therefore, the solution for this homogeneous equation is $e^x$ and $xe^{x}$. Now if we want to find a particular solution $y'' - 2y' + y = 2e^x$. Normally we set the particular solution to be $Ae^{x}$. However, it duplicates with the solution of the homogeneous solution, therefore, we multiple it with $x$ and it becomes $Axe^x$, but it still duplicates with $xe^{x}$. Therefore, we mupltiply it by $x^2$, and the particular solution is given by $Ax^2e^{x}$.

Answer (score 2):

$y^{\prime \prime}−3y^{\prime}+2y= 2e^x$. Use operator D:

Let $D = d/dx$. So, $(D^2 - 3D + 2)y_p = 2e^x \quad \Rightarrow \quad (D-1)(D-2)y_p = 2e^x \quad \Rightarrow$

$y_p = \dfrac{1}{(D-1)(D-2)}\cdot 2e^x = 2e^x\dfrac{1}{(D+1-1)(D+1-2)}\cdot 1 = 2e^x\dfrac{1}{D(D-1)}\cdot 1 \quad \Rightarrow$

$y_p = 2e^x\dfrac{1}{D(0-1)\cdot 1} = -2e^x\dfrac{1}{D}\cdot 1 = -2xe^x$

Look this blog: http://fatosmatematicos.blogspot.com/2011/02/o-metodo-da-chave-invertida-para-achar.html

Answer (score 1):

The simplest thing in your case is probably to use this (easily justified) trick:

If $p(x)$ is a one variable polynomial with complex coefficients and $c$ a complex number, then the ODE
$$
p\left(\frac{d}{dx}\right)y=e^{cx}
$$
has a solution of the form $e^{cx}\,q(x)$ where $q(x)$ is a polynomial whose degree is the number of roots of $p(x)$ equal to $c$.

In you case, $p(x)=(x-1)(x-2)$, $c=1$, so the trick tells you to look for a solution of the form 
$$
(ax+b)\ e^x,
$$
and you can clearly assume $b=0$.